# Compute distance between rows in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame filled with zeros except from some 1.0 values. For each row, I want to compute the distance to the next occurence of 1.0. Any idea how to do it ?

input dataframe:

```
index col1
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     1.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     1.0
8     0.0
```

Expected output dataframe:

```
index col1
0     4.0
1     3.0
2     2.0
3     1.0
4     0.0
5     2.0
6     1.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby(df['col1'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False)
print (df)
   col1  new
0   0.0    4
1   0.0    3
2   0.0    2
3   0.0    1
4   1.0    0
5   0.0    2
6   0.0    1
7   1.0    0
8   0.0    0
```

**Explanation**:

First compare by `1` with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
print (df['col1'].eq(1))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Then swap ordering by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (df['col1'].eq(1).iloc[::-1])
8    False
7     True
6    False
5    False
4     True
3    False
2    False
1    False
0    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Create groups by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
print (df['col1'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum())
8    0
7    1
6    1
5    1
4    2
3    2
2    2
1    2
0    2
Name: col1, dtype: int32
```

Pass groups to [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False` for count from back:

```
print (df.groupby(df['col1'].eq(1).iloc[::-1].cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False))
0    4
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    0
5    2
6    1
7    0
8    0
dtype: int64
```